# Uncaught ReferenceError: Row is not defined React-foundation

Tags: reactjs, zurb-foundation

I've installed Foundation on my react project and even after importing it, it still can not define foundation

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Link, IndexLink } from 'react-router';
import Auth from '../modules/Auth';
import DrawerLeft from './Drawer.jsx';
import Foundation from 'react-foundation';


const Base = ({ children }) => (
  <div>
    <div className="top-bar">
      <Row>
        <Column small={2} large={4}>TESTING</Column>
      </Row>

      {Auth.isUserAuthenticated() ? (
        <div className="top-bar-right">
          <Link to="/logout">Exit</Link>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div className="top-bar-right">
          <Link to="/login">Enter</Link>
          <Link to="/signup">Join</Link>
        </div>
      )}

    </div>

    { /* child component will be rendered here */ }
    {children}
  </div>
);

Base.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default Base;
```

And in my package.json it says "react-foundation": "^0.8.2" under dependencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import it like this

```
import { Row, Column } from 'react-foundation';
```

Also you'll need `Column`

Comment: Or use it like this: `<ReactFoundation.Row>...</ReactFoundation.Row>`

Comment: @Alexander Thought named import is better for tree shaking.

Answer (score 1):

From the [npm package link to the Grid Code](https://github.com/digiaonline/react-foundation/blob/HEAD/src/components/grid.js), you can see that `Row` and `Column` are `named exports` in `react-foundation`, so you can import them as

```
 import {Row, Column} from 'react-foundation';
```

and use them